# Graphic or Graphical part of the project? Which is correct?

Tags: word-choice

My question relates to software project. Which form is correct?

1. I am responsible for graphic part of the project?
2. I am responsible for graphical part of the project?
3. I am responsible for graphics part of the project?

Comment: This has been answered on the ELU site: [What is the difference between “graphic” and “graphical” as adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167034/what-is-the-difference-between-graphic-and-graphical-as-adjectives)

Comment: I have seen this and still don't know which to choose

Comment: In your use case I would use 3: I am responsible for the graphics.